# How would I create a formula only using declared int's in C?

Tags: c

I'm not sure if I worded my question properly, but here is what I'm basically looking for. I'm currently working on an assignment for school practicing using functions in my code. I'm having trouble reusing a certain function by altering the operation in the function.

```
int ArithmeticOptionGame(int Operation)
{
int MaxNumber, AmtOfProblems, i, Answer = 0, Choice;
printf("What is the maximum number you would like?\n");
scanf("%d", &MaxNumber);
printf("How many problems would you like?\n");
scanf("%d", &AmtOfProblems);

int start = time(0);

for(i = 0; i < AmtOfProblems; i++)
{
int j = (rand() % MaxNumber) + 1;
int k = (rand() % MaxNumber) + 1;
printf("What is %d %d %d:\n", j, Operation, k);

/* What goes here for the answer formula */

scanf("%d", &Choice);
if(Choice == Answer)
{
printf("Correct! Great Job!\n");
}
else
{
    printf("Sorry, that's incorrect. The answer is %d\n", Answer);
    TotalScore -= 5;
}
}
int end = time(0);

TimeSpent = end - start;
TimeConvertedToScorePoints();
TotalScore /= AmtOfProblems;


return;
}
```

Depending on what I need for my operation whether it's +, -, /, *, etc. how would I code it under the `printf` line. I've already tried:

```
Answer = j Operation k;
```

Which I know is wrong, but figured I'd try. Again, not sure if this is even possible or would I need to just create a separate function for each operation?

Comment: Function pointers may be useful.

Comment: I think showing declarations of variables is more important than making question short.

Comment: I can post my whole program, not to many lines, if needed. Unfortunately, we haven't learned about function pointers yet, so I can't use anything that we haven't learned yet.

Answer (score 1):

Given that this is an assignment for an introductory class, I think that using an explicit `switch` statement would be the preferred way.

```
double
compute(const double lhs, const double rhs, const char op)
{
  switch (op)
    {
    case '+':
      return lhs + rhs;
    case '-':
      return lhs - rhs;
    case '*':
      return lhs * rhs;
    case '/':
      return lhs / rhs;
    default:
      fprintf(stderr, "error: unknown operation: %c\n", op);
      abort();
    }
}
```

I have intentionally altered the setting a little so you'll have to transfer the concept back to your exercise.

Comment: We haven't learned about switch statements yet, so I can't use those. I understand the concept of how they work and see why they would work perfectly here. I'll try to implement myself and see how it goes. Thank you so much for all your help!

Comment: If you can't use `switch`, you can just as easily use a bunch of `if`s/`else`s to do the same thing as a `switch`.

Comment: @RastaJedi Oh wow....Of course! I can't believe I didn't already think of that....embarrassing. Thank you!

Comment: @Michael Benton haha no problem, no need to be embarrassed. Good luck and have fun :).